# ORA-00905: missing keyword when using Case in order by

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have the below query, where if the edit date is not null, then the most recent record needs to be returned and also should be randomized else the records should be randomized. I tried the below order by , but I am getting the missing keyword error.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT c.id,c.edit_date, c.name,l.title
                                          FROM tableA c, tableb l
                                         WHERE c.id = l.id
                                           AND c.published_ind = 'Y'
                                           AND lc.type_id != 4 
                                           AND TRIM(c.img_file) IS NOT NULL
                                        ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
                                   )
                         WHERE ROWNUM = 1

     order by case  when c.edit_date = 'null' 
           then DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
           else DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE, c.edit_date desc
     end
```

Comment: A case expression returns one value. It's not used for conditional execution of code.

Comment: @jarlh - I don't see "conditional execution" anywhere, I just see the `case` expression used in the `order by` clause. That is a valid use.

Comment: @mathguy, 
 
Seems like OP wants to sort by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (when c.edit_date = 'null'), or else by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE, c.edit_date desc. I.e. either by one thing or else by another thing. Some kind of conditional execution.

Comment: In an Answer I showed you why you are getting that error and how to fix it. Now, it is possible that after you correct it, you will get more errors, or that your query will not do what you wanted. If you are trying to solve a problem and don't know how, DON'T post a query that doesn't work as intended. Just state the original problem and see if we can help.

Comment: Ok, so I posted the query I have and also wrote what I intend to do, I am not sure what else I am missing here? My original query only orders by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE, what i intend to do is, if the edit date has a value,  I want to order by that date and then I want those records to be returned in a randomized manner..hope this makes sense. thank you again for your inputs

Comment: You can't return two columns in the `else` part. And you can't have the `desc` attribute _inside_ the `case`

Comment: Ohh... NOW I see the `end`.  You do have it, but in the wrong place. I didn't realize you were trying to "output" two columns from the `case` expression.

Comment: So, let's try to state the problem more clearly. The query will not help (for example: in the outer SELECT you are selecting only one row, so it is not clear why you are ordering that as it is still just ONE ROW). So. The problem. You are joining two tables, and the result set has four columns. Then you are picking just one random row from this result set? That's what the query does. Then you look at the edit_date, and if it is not null you want to do something else? What?

Comment: So, yes I need only 1 row from the results set and it needs to be randomized. which is what the original query is doing. Now, I need to factor the edit date into the query and do this - retrieve most recently updated and the newest record first in rotations. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correct, you try to get a record per ID with either the highest date (a random one if more records with the same date exists) or with a NULL date (again random one when more NULL records with the same ID exists.

So assuming this data

```
        ID EDIT_DATE           TEXT
---------- ------------------- ----
         1 01.01.2015 00:00:00 A    
         1 01.01.2016 00:00:00 B    
         1 01.01.2016 00:00:00 C    
         2 01.01.2015 00:00:00 D    
         2 01.01.2016 00:00:00 E    
         2                     F    
         2                     G
```

You expect either B or C for ID =1 and either F or G for ID = 2.

This query do it.
The features used are *ordering with NULLS FIRST* and *adding a random value as a last ordering column* - to get random result if all preceeding columns are the same..

```
with dta as (
select  1 id, to_date('01012015','ddmmyyyy') edit_date, 'A' text from dual union all
select  1 id, to_date('01012016','ddmmyyyy') edit_date, 'B' text from dual union all
select  1 id, to_date('01012016','ddmmyyyy') edit_date, 'C' text from dual union all
select  2 id, to_date('01012015','ddmmyyyy') edit_date, 'D' text from dual union all
select  2 id, to_date('01012016','ddmmyyyy') edit_date, 'E' text from dual union all
select  2 id, NULL edit_date, 'F' text from dual union all
select  2 id, NULL edit_date, 'G' text from dual),
dta2 as (
select ID, EDIT_DATE, TEXT,
row_number() over (partition by ID order by edit_date DESC NULLS first, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) as rn
from dta)
select *
from dta2 where rn = 1
order by id
;

        ID EDIT_DATE           TEXT         RN
---------- ------------------- ---- ----------
         1 01.01.2016 00:00:00 B             1 
         2                     F             1
```

Hopefully you can re-use thhe idea if you need a bit different result...

Comment: thanks for your inputs, i am still trying to figure this one out, any ideas will be appreciated. So, each ID will only have 1 record, if edit_dt is not null, then I want to randomly get that record first is that possible to do. I need only 1 row from the results set and it needs to be randomized. which is what the original query is doing. Now, I need to factor the edit date into the query and do this - retrieve most recently updated and the newest record first in rotations.thanks in advance

Comment: @user747291 I re-read your comment several time, but I'm not realy sure if I understod it. Maybe you could provide sample data with expected results (more result that would illustrate the randomness).

Answer (score 0):

Statement `WHERE` always apply before statement `ORDER BY`. So in your query at first will applied `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` and only after that will applied `order by case` ... for single record.
Perhaps you need add another subquery that at first execute `ORDER BY`, get rowset in proper order and after that execute `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` to select single row.

Statment `ORDER BY ... DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE, c.edit_date` look strange. In fact, recordset will be sorted by `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` and if rowset has couple of rows have equal `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` we additionally will sort them by `c.edit_date`.